# How to search for text in sql server when storing different languages

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, html-encode

I have a website that has product names containing French and English words. When I store a product name I store it as html encoded in the ProductName field in my SQL Server. For example the word Château is stored as **Ch& #226;teau** in my database.

If someone wants to search for a product name I htmlencode the search term. This will successfully return a match for the search term Château but if someone types in Chateau (which most english users would) I don't get any results returned from my LIKE statement. This is correct as Chateau does not match Château.

What I would like to be able to do is let someone search for something like the word Château by simply typing Chateau.

Any ideas how I could go about this? I am using asp.net C# 3.5 SP1 and Sql Server 05.

Comment: how about displaying similar phonetic words matching, if no result found or additional to results?

Comment: That would be pretty cool but any examples I've looked at are hugely over complicated for this solution. I'd say I'll probably just have to save the product names without htmlencoding them and then use collation casting as per examples below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    product_name 
from 
    products 
where 
    product_name Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI like 'Chateau'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the values are stored as HTML Encoded. I have updated my answer to make this clearer - the site editor converted my value to html ;) Would you recommend I store the french wording without encoding it in my database? thanks.

Comment: Yes, store it directly with accents in the database. Never store HTML encoded entities in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to use collation casting; in your case, use "accent insensitive" collations, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ProductName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE 'Chateau' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI;
```

Check your collations and adjust them as necessary (notice the ending "_AI" which means "accent insensitive").

A more advanced option would be to use [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Let us know if you need help with that.